# When applying an XSL template to one of two different source files, how can I reference a "matching" node in the other source?

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0

I am using XSLT to transform information from two difference source XMLs. Each relevant node in the first source has a node with an equivalent "id" attribute in the second source file which contains extra information that needs to be merged. Any nodes in the second source that don't have a match don't matter, so the first source needs to drive the results.

Here is a simplified version of the problem:

XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:two="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/1.0">

    <xsl:param name="secondDoc" as="document-node()" />

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Employees>
            <xsl:apply-templates match="$secondDoc/two:People/two:Person" />
        <Employees>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="two:Person">
        <Employee>
            <xsl:value-of select="/Employees/Employee[@id='@id']/FirstName" />
            <xsl:value-of select="two:LastName" />
        </Employee>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Employees>
    <Employee id="1">
        <FirstName>John</FirstName>
    </Employee>
</Employees>
```

Second Source:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People xmlns="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/1.0">
    <Person id="1">
        <LastName>Doe</LastName>
    </Person>
</People>
```

The method I am trying to use is to create templates that match to the namespace prefix used by the second source, and then match to the equivalent node from within the template. The problem is that I'm not sure how to XPath back to the root template. The value-of statements fails, of course.

One method I tried is to add a xsl:with-param to xsl:apply-templates> and send the matching node as a variable to the template. This worked if I selected a node manually (Employee[1]), but since the with-param doesn't seem to take the context of the apply-templates select, I'm not sure how to tie the "id" attributes together.

Is there a way to reference back to the root template, or am I going about this the wrong way?

**EDIT**: I thought of a possible solution,  although it may not be the cleanest. I could pass the "Employees" node as a parameter to the template and then match up the "id" tags for the specific employee inside the template and use the resulting node as the reference. This looks like passing the root node in this example, but in reality this is a small section of the overall XSL. Hopefully there's an easier way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a variable to store a reference to the root node of the primary input document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:two="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/1.0">

    <xsl:param name="secondDoc" as="document-node()" />

    <xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Employees>
            <xsl:apply-templates match="$secondDoc/two:People/two:Person" />
        <Employees>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="two:Person">
        <Employee>
            <xsl:value-of select="$main-root/Employees/Employee[@id = current()/@id]/FirstName" />
            <xsl:value-of select="two:LastName" />
        </Employee>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And then of course use a key for the cross-reference:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:two="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/1.0">

    <xsl:param name="secondDoc" as="document-node()" />

    <xsl:key name="id" match="Employee" use="@id"/>
    <xsl:variable name="main-root" select="/"/>    
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <Employees>
            <xsl:apply-templates match="$secondDoc/two:People/two:Person" />
        <Employees>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="two:Person">
        <Employee>
            <xsl:value-of select="key('id', @id, $main-root)/FirstName" />
            <xsl:value-of select="two:LastName" />
        </Employee>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is the way I'll go. I'll try it with a timer since I'm curious as to how it might affect performance.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different method, picking up on what you said about the first source driving the results, and calling in the seoncd source. This might be useful:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:two="http://www.mycompany.com/schemas/1.0" version="2.0">

<xsl:variable name="source2" select="doc('source2.xml')"></xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <Employees>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="/Employees/Employee"/>
    </Employees>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Employee">
    <Employee>
        <xsl:value-of select="FirstName" />
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="$source2/two:People/two:Person[@id=current()/@id]/two:LastName" />
    </Employee>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I'll look into this method. The problem may be that the second source is based on some internal objects and is probably being sent to the transformer as a parameter (a string I think), and the first source is the "actual" source.